# Please somebody help me with this error in getting transactionReceipt : "TypeError: contract.deploymentTransaction.wait is not a function"

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment, javascript, etherjs

```
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  // http://127.0.0.1:7545
  let provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0xb837e61da0f71b2b895e3b165dac7e883e25cf34b6284f6e1118a45e99013e14",
    provider
  );
  const abi = fs.readFileSync(
    "./ethers-simple-storage_SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi",
    "utf8"
  );
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    "./ethers-simple-storage_SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
    "utf8"
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait....");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(); //STOP here! Wait for contrat to be deployed.

  const transactionReceipt = await contract.deploymentTransaction.wait(1);
  console.log(transactionReceipt);

  console.log("Done!");
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

My instructor used this code

```
const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1)
```

but when I try to write `deploy.Transaction` it automatically writes `deploymentTransaction`. Please help me with this Im stuck for hours now!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

remove this line:

```
const transactionReceipt = await contract.deploymentTransaction.wait(1);
```

And replace it by this:

```
const transactionReceipt = await contract.deploymentTransaction().wait(1);
```

`deploymentTransaction` is a function, [see documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/contract/#BaseContract-deploymentTransaction).